# Android: NetworkOnMainThreadException on Thread

Tags: android, sockets, networking, service

Just as the title says. I'm getting this error when starting a Service that uses sockets. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are attempting to use sockets on the main application thread, perhaps from `onStartCommand()`. Please do network I/O on a background thread.